# Neo4j How to call different properties for the same relationship

Tags: neo4j, properties, relationship, similarity

I'm using the new algo to calculate similarities, algo.similarity.jaccard and algo.similarity.overlap with the option WRITE, it means, in the relationship SIMILARITY I create properties sim_jaccard and sim_overlap. 
The problem comes when I call these two properties, for example :

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[s:SIMILARITY]-> (u2:User)
WITH coalesce(s.sim_jaccard,0) AS sim_jaccard, coalesce(s.sim_overlap,0)  AS sim_overlap
RETURN sim_jaccard, sim_overlap
LIMIT 25
```

I get:

```
sim_jaccard  sim_overlap
0            0.8507462686567164
0            0.9253731343283582 
0            0.8208955223880597
0            0.8955223880597015
```

I think that happens because properties id are different in the relationship:

```
SIMILARITY <id>: 3300778 sim_overlap: 1.0
SIMILARITY <id>: 2453827 sim_jaccard: 0.6268656716417911
```

I would like to have:

```
SIMILARITY <id>: 3300778 sim_overlap: 1.0,  sim_jaccard: 0.6268656716417911
```

Any idea to solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your graph so the relationships are combined into 1, then APOC Procedures has some [refactor procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_merging_nodes) to merge relationships together (just use the `combine` value for the given properties).

If you just want your return to combine the values into a single line, then you can modify your query to sum the values for all rels between the two nodes:

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(u2:User)
WHERE id(u1) < id(u2)
WITH u1, u2, sum(coalesce(s.sim_jaccard,0)) AS sim_jaccard, sum(coalesce(s.sim_overlap,0))  AS sim_overlap
RETURN sim_jaccard, sim_overlap
LIMIT 25
```

For the approach where you need to MERGE nodes, you'll want to collect the relationships with respect to the end nodes before calling the procedure:

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(u2:User)
WHERE id(u1) < id(u2)
WITH u1, u2, collect(s) as rels
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships(rels, {properties:'combine'}) YIELD rel
RETURN count(rel)
```

sum(coalesce(s.sim_jaccard,0)) AS sim_jaccard, sum(coalesce(s.sim_overlap,0))  AS sim_overlap
    RETURN sim_jaccard, sim_overlap
    LIMIT 25

Comment: Yes, I need to merge relationships together, so apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships([rels],{config}) should solve my problem. Please, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? :                                                call apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships([MATCH (u1:User)-[s:SIMILARITY]->(u2:User)],{properties:'combine'}), because it doesn't work. Thanks!